# WinObjC - Windows bridge for iOS - Getting blank black screen - Xib2Nib error

Tags: windows-10, winobjc

I am trying to convert my iOS application to Windows 10 application using WinObjC SDK.

I was able to successfully create the .sln file of the project.

I tried to build this using local machine but it was showing an error related to "Xib2Nib.exe", saying it was unable to convert LaunchScreen.xib (error exit code 255). So I removed the LaunchScreen.xib file from my project. Now there is just a Main.storyboard file for UI.

I again tried to build the application and I was able to build it successfully, but the application is just showing the navigation title and a blank black screen.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to be aware of the fact that the Windows Bridge for iOS is still in a very early stage. You can find a list on what is still under development [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki#whats-still-under-development). Xib and storyboard support is one of the features which is not jet completed as you can also see in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/issues/112) issue.
So I guess you only have to wait a bit longer and keep track of the project on it's [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC) page :)

Comment: I have seen the reply on that issue posted on github. That issue is posted by me only :P .. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Oh, ok ;) You can also write the Team on their IRC channel; they are very responsive!